# Generic constraints and interface implementation/inheritance

Tags: c#, generics

Not entirely sure how to phrase the question, because it's a "why doesn't this work?" type of query.

I've reduced my particular issue down to this code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
}

public class Bar<T> where T : IFoo
{
    public Bar(T t)
    {
    }

    public Bar()
        : this(new Foo()) // cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'T'
    {
    }
}
```

Now, the generic type `T` in the `Bar<T>` class *must* implement IFoo. So why does the compiler give me the error in the comment? Surely an instance of Foo is an IFoo, and can therefore be passed around as a representative of the generic type `T`?

Is this a compiler limitation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could also have a Fiz that implements IFoo that is not related to Foo in any other way:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
}

public class Fiz : IFoo
{
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
Fiz fiz = foo; // Not gonna compile.
```

What you want is probably more like:

```
public class Bar<T> where T : IFoo, new()
{
    public Bar(T t)
    {
    }

    public Bar()
        : this(new T()) 
    {
    }
}
```

So you can have

```
Bar<Foo> barFoo = new Bar<Foo>();
Bar<Fiz> barFiz = new Bar<Fiz>();
```

Comment: This is sweet as I didn't know you could the new T() thing, you just saved my life in a project I am working on. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you create a class Baz and then the generic type Bar baz = new Bar(), new Foo() as defined by your constructor overload, would not be of type T, in this case Baz.

Comment: +1 Thanks yshuditelu. I'm giving Andrew the accepted answer since his is a little more complete with the code samples (and you were only 8 seconds apart). :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because if you create a class:

```
public class Fred : IFoo
{
}
```

And then instantiate `Bar<T>` like this:

```
var bar = new Bar<Fred>();
```

Then it violates the constraints of the class as a `Foo` is not a `Fred` which is the current `T`.

You can force it to compile by putting the cast sequence `(T)(IFoo)new Foo()` in the constructor, but you'll get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime if the actual type of `T` is not assignable from `Foo`.