# Converting from generic type to its constraint interface

Tags: vb.net, generics, type-conversion

I have created a generic class, with the constraint IComparable, as follows:

```
Public Class Foo(Of T As IComparable)
    Private _f As T

    Public Sub New(ByVal f As T)
        _f = f
    End Sub

    Public Function GetBar() As Bar
        Return New Bar(Me) 'compiler error: Value of type Foo(of T) 
                           'cannot be converted to Foo(of IComparable)
    End Function

End Class
```

I have another class which takes as a constructor argument an object of the first class defined:

```
Public Class Bar
    Private _foo As Foo(Of IComparable)

    Public Sub New(ByVal foo As Foo(Of IComparable))
        _foo = foo
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, I get the shown error when trying to create the Bar object.

Can anybody explain why am I getting this error? I would expect the compiler to know that type T is any IComparable type...

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418764/generic-constraints-and-interface-implementation-inheritance), but I don't know how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect the compiler to know that type T is any IComparable type...

Yes, it knows that - but your `Bar` constructor is expecting a `Foo(Of IComparable)` not a `Foo(Of T)` where `T` implements `IComparable`. You want generic covariance, but that can't be applied to classes in .NET (only interfaces and delegates).

One option is to make `Bar` generic as well, with another type parameter `T` which is constrained to implement `IComparable`. Then your `Foo.GetBar()` method could return a `Bar(Of T)`.